# Android- how to scroll up the selected item in scroll view using getTop()

Tags: android, scroll

My application need to scroll up(means scroll up to top of the screen) the selected item in the scroll view using `getTop()` method. Is it possible? Then how to do it?

Thanks.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to scroll to top of long ScrollView layout?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4119441/how-to-scroll-to-top-of-long-scrollview-layout)