# The screen will push to bottom in ScrollView when I add a listview in android

Tags: android, android-layout, scrollview

I am working on a listview that can be expandable ,that means I include the listview in an scrollview, different from the listview default behavior , the listview height will now be its actual size , and I scroll through the scroll view instead of listview. The below code is my implementation , the problem is , when the listview expand the screen will push to bottom, how can I keep the screen view at the top? Thanks

```
ListAdapter customAdapter = new LeadersAdapter(this,R.layout.leader_record_row, records);
        results.setAdapter(customAdapter);
        updateListViewHeight(results);

public static void updateListViewHeight(ListView myListView) {
         ListAdapter myListAdapter = myListView.getAdapter();
         if (myListAdapter == null) {            
                  return;
         }
        //get listview height
        int totalHeight = 0;
        int adapterCount = myListAdapter.getCount();
        for (int size = 0; size < adapterCount ; size++) {
            View listItem = myListAdapter.getView(size, null, myListView);
            listItem.measure(0, 0);
            totalHeight += listItem.getMeasuredHeight();
        }
        //Change Height of ListView 
        ViewGroup.LayoutParams params = myListView.getLayoutParams();
        params.height = totalHeight + (myListView.getDividerHeight() * (adapterCount - 1));
        myListView.setLayoutParams(params);
    }
```

XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/share_bg" >

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

            <RelativeLayout
                android:id="@+id/lbd_top_section"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/lbd_logo"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="10dp" />

                <RelativeLayout
                    android:id="@+id/lbd_my_info"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/lbd_logo" >

                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/lbd_user_pic"
                        android:layout_width="50dp"
                        android:layout_height="50dp"/>

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/lbd_user_name"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/lbd_user_pic"
                        android:paddingTop="5dp"
                        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/lbd_user_pic"
                        android:textColor="@android:color/white" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/lbd_user_pt"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_below="@+id/lbd_user_name"
                        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/lbd_user_pic"
                        android:textColor="@color/dark_orange" />
                </RelativeLayout>
            </RelativeLayout>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/lbd_name_tag"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_below="@+id/lbd_top_section"
                android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                android:text="@string/leader_board_name"
                android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                android:textSize="20sp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/lbd_pt_tag"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_alignTop="@+id/lbd_name_tag"
                android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
                android:text="@string/leader_board_pt"
                android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                android:textSize="20sp" />

            <ListView
                android:id="@+id/lbd_listview"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:layout_below="@+id/lbd_name_tag" >
            </ListView>
        </RelativeLayout>
    </ScrollView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Use this in list view android:stackFromBottom="false"

Comment: Thanks for your reply, the list view still push to bottom

Comment: It's not your listview problem you need to alter in scrollview check this http://stackoverflow.com/a/4774007/1765530

Comment: scroll_view.smoothScrollTo(0,0) works for me. Thanks a lot