# Having error with ScrollView and selectable TextView...Why?

Tags: android, textview, scrollview

Hello guys I'm working for my jokes app, and I've TextViews for that but each time I open up my Activity the `ScrollView` automatically scrolls down to bottom! And to solve this problem I set `android:focusable="false"`
then my problem was solved, but now I can't use `android:textIsSelectable="true"`! My `TextView` dosen't get selected I've tried every solution for that but it didn't worked!!! I've done it in XMLs and also in Java Activities like :

`tv.setTextIsSelectable (true);
tv.setFocusable(false);`

Hope you got my problem, thanks!

XML for `TextView`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/sv_bf"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#ffffff"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="15dp" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/belief_quotes"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#ffffff"
        android:text="@string/belief_quotes"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textSize="22sp" 
        android:textIsSelectable="true"
        android:focusable="false"/>

</ScrollView>
```

Comment: You should post your xml code first.

Comment: what you have in xml, listview or just bunch of textviews?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4119441/how-to-scroll-to-top-of-long-scrollview-layout ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can put this on your Activity's onCreate section after setting content view:

```
final ScrollView mainScrollView=(ScrollView)findViewById(R.id.YOURSCROLLVIEW);
mainScrollView.smoothScrollTo(0, 0);
```