# recyclerview inside scroll view affects scroll position

Tags: android

I have the following layout structure

```
  --FrameLayout
    --scrollview
       --LinearLayout
          --LinearLayout
          --RecyclerView
    --LinearLayout
```

When I arrive at the page, it seems to scroll to the recycler view.
I just want scroll position to be at the top when arriving at the page.

Seems odd, When i switch the order between the linearlayoout and recyclerview inside the scrollview, then the behaviour is correct - as in the scroll position is at the top

Comment: Post some of you code pleas, also you're ASCII drawing says that the scrollview holdes two child's, which it can't.

Comment: my mistake, corrected

Comment: seriously not understandable.. Please use some images & code be more descriptive..!! And **RecycleView inside ScrollView is always weird** check this [1st](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27083091/recyclerview-inside-scrollview-is-not-working), [2nd](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32420770/use-recyclerview-inside-scrollview-with-flexible-recycler-item-height).

Comment: @jankigadhiya - not really. You can have horizontal recyclerview inside vertical scrollview, but if both are vertical - for sure it is bad

Answer (score 18, accepted):

This worked for me:

```
mRecyclerView.setFocusable(false);
```

Although a lot of good answers here: [How to scroll to top of long ScrollView layout?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4119441/how-to-scroll-to-top-of-long-scrollview-layout)